# Colour as a coding mechanism

Tags: color-scheme, cognition

When using colour as a coding mechanism, the number of colours used should be:

a. 7 or fewer
b. 9 or fewer
c. 6 or fewer
d. 8 or fewer

Potentially a question for cognisc Stack Exchange but this question relates to the amount of colours a user can perceive at a given moment and in terms of UX, I guess, assigning colours to categorise elements.

For example, how many colours can the human brain take in at a given moment of time without over-complicating a design. For example, according to Dr Halberda (2006) colour plays a major role in catching the attention of people. One can select and attend up to 70 items at once if they are of the same colour. Colour-coding helps to keep things organised and simple. But what Halberda failed to account for is how many colours can be categorised at a given moment in time.

These are the only answers providing by the organisation body so unable to give a min or max answer. The meaning of fewer is less

Comment: Needs much more context. What is the max number, what is the min number? What is the meaning of ewer?

Comment: You mean like the colour coding in the [new Gmail app](http://droiddog.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/2013-06-03-12.38.18.png)?

Comment: Edited comment to account  for context.@AndriodHustle - similar yes, so how many can we interpret at a given moment without forgetting what each colour is intended to represent?

Comment: Can we remove the multiple choice options from the question? It sounds like you want us to answer an exam question for you.

Comment: You might be interested in Trello's treatment of the subject, regarding its use of colored labels as well as being able to switch to patterns instead of colors for color-blindness: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19129/is-it-possible-to-have-more-than-six-labels-in-trello

Answer (score 0):

We don't know what precisely you want to do with colours. But **don't rely on colour alone to convey information**. Otherwise your work would not be **accessible**. There are **colour-blind people**. And, if you do use colours, **choose colours not close to each other**.